# ifstream not reading EOF character

Tags: c++, ifstream, eof

I am creating a program (In C++) that takes an ASCII file and reads a few values from each line until it reaches the end of the file.  I am using `ifstream` to read the file, and I have never had problems with it stopping when I use the `ifstream.eof()` method.  This time, however, even though it found the eof character in my test case, when I analyzed my other files, it is infinite looping because it never finds the eof character.  Is this a coding issue, or an issue with my files?

```
string line = "";
unsigned long pos = 0;
ifstream curfile(input.c_str());
getline(curfile, line);
int linenumber = 0;
cout<<"About to try to read the file"<<endl;
if (!curfile.good())
    cout<<"Bad file read"<<endl;
while (!curfile.eof())
{

    cout<<"Getting line "<<linenumber<<endl;
    linenumber++;
    pos = line.find_first_of(' ');
    line = line.substr(pos+1, line.size()-1);
    pos = line.find_first_of(' ');
    current.push_back(atof(line.substr(0, pos).c_str()));
    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        pos = line.find_first_of(' ');
        line = line.substr(pos+1, line.size()-1);
    }
    pos = line.find_first_of(' ');
    dx.push_back(atof(line.substr(0, pos).c_str()));
    pos = line.find_first_of(' ');
    line = line.substr(pos+1, line.size()-1);
    pos = line.find_first_of(' ');
    dy.push_back(atof(line.substr(0, pos).c_str()));
    getline(curfile, line);
}
```

EDIT: When I first run the loop, currentfile.good() returns false...what am I doing that causes it to return that?

Comment: Is this the new big C++ anti-pattern or what?

Comment: Could you post the code inside the loop? I think the problem might be in that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ eof() problem - never returns true?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842030/c-eof-problem-never-returns-true)

Comment: I was referring to `while(!stream.eof())`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing is first, you shouldn't check like that. `eof()` doesn't return `true` until **after** a failed read. But you can do better (and easier)!

**check the stream state with the implicit conversion to `void*` which can be used in a `bool` context**. Since most of the read operations on streams return a reference to the stream, you can write some very consice code like this:

```
std::string line;
while(std::getline(currentfile, line)) {
    // process line
}
```

Basically what it is doing is saying "while I could successfully extract a line from `currentfile`, do the following", which is what you really meant to say anyway ;-);

Like I said, this applies to most stream operations, so you can do things like this:

```
int x;
std::string y;
if(std::cin >> x >> y) {
    // successfully read an integer and a string from cin!
}
```

**EDIT**: The way I would rewrite your code is like this:

```
string line;
unsigned long pos = 0;
int linenumber = 0;

ifstream curfile(input.c_str());

std::cout << "About to try to read the file" << std::endl;
while (std::getline(curfile, line)) {

    std::cout << "Getting line " << linenumber << std::endl;
    linenumber++;

    // do the rest of the work with line
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and it never enters the loop (Output says "About to try to read the file" but then never says "Getting Line xxx")

Comment: Try my simplified version of your code, does it output "Getting line x"? If not, then I think there is something else wrong...

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's an implicit conversion to `void *`, not `bool` ([reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/))

Comment: currentfile.good() does not return true when I check that right before the loop starts

Comment: @mrswmmr: are you saying that in my example, right after the `ifstream curfile(input.c_str());` line, `curfile.good()` is `false`?

Comment: @mrswmmr: That means something failed before your loop even started.  Probably the open().

Answer (score 2):

Do not do it like that.

`EOF` is not the only thing you'll encounter while reading. There's a bunch of errors you might get, and so the best is to simply test the stream itself:

```
while(currentfile)
{
    // read somehow
}
```

If you're reading lines, then, the simplest way is:

```
std::string line;
while(std::getline(currentfile, line))
{
    // use line
}
```

Comment: Does that detect EOF?  I thought you needed `while (currentfile.good())` to check all of `eofbit`, `badbit`, and `failbit`...

Comment: If it never actually reads the lines, then `currentfile.eof()` will return `false`, `currentfile.good()` will also return `false`, and `currentfile.fail()` will return `true`.  i.e., you will have a failed read; and your loop is not currently set up to handle a failed read, so you incorrect behavior. (And, @Nemo:  either `good()` or converting the stream to `bool` as shown in the answer will return the same thing).

Answer (score 2):

Your first call to `getline` is triggering one of the fail-bits on the `ifstream` object.  That is why if you do a check for a fail-bit using `ios::good()`, you never enter your read loop.  I would check to see what the value of `line` is ... it's probably empty, meaning you're having another issue reading your file, like maybe permissions problems, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
if (!curfile.good())
    cout<<"Bad file read"<<endl;   // OK you print bad.
while (!curfile.eof())             // But the loop is still entered.
                                   // Another reason to **NEVER** to use 
                                   // while (file.eof()) // as bad does not mean eof
                                                         // though eof is bad
```

Try this:

```
void readFile(std::istream& str)
{   
    std::string     line;
    while(std::getline(str, line))
    {
        std::stringstream   lineStream(line);
        std::string         ignoreWord;
        int                 number[3];

        lineStream >> ignoreWord   // reads one space seporated word
                   >> number[0]    // reads a number
                   >> ignoreWord >> ignoreWord >> ignoreWords  // reads three words 
                   >> number[1]    // reads a number
                   >> number[2];   // reads a number

        current.push_back(number[0]);
        dx.push_back(number[1]);
        dy.push_back(number[2]);
    }   
}
```