# std::ifstream eof difference between libc++ and libstdc++11

Tags: c++, clang, ifstream, libstdc++, libc++

I have got this code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    const std::string path = "/tmp/some_random_path"; // this file do not exist before running of program
    std::ofstream file_output(path);
    std::ifstream file_input(path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    file_input.peek();

    if (!file_input.eof()) {
        return 1;
    }
    std::vector<char> data = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    file_output.write(data.data(), static_cast<long>(data.size()));
    file_output.flush();

    file_input.clear();
    file_input.peek();
    if (file_input.eof()) {
        return 2; // libc++
    }
    return 0; // libstdc++11
}
```

My specs:

> lsb_release -a
> No LSB modules are available.
> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
> Description:  Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
> Release:  20.04
> Codename: focal

> clang++ -v
> Ubuntu clang version 15.0.7
> Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
> Thread model: posix
> InstalledDir: /usr/bin
> Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10
> Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
> Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10
> Candidate multilib: .;@m64
> Selected multilib: .;@m64

libstdc++11 compile command: clang++ main.cpp

libc++ compile command: clang++ -stdlib=libc++ main.cpp

I expect success return code for both libc++ and libstdc++11, but libc++ eof flag is not updated. Is it valid?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.eof() loop not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734116/eof-loop-not-working)

Comment: Sounds like clang issue. I've tried `g++` `11.2.0-1.3` with 4 options: default, c++11, c++17 and c++20. In all four cases got return code 0.

Comment: @PepijnKramer no, this do not answer my question. Or, if it's possible, could you describe, why this link could answer my question?

Comment: @DmitryMesserman this is definitely not a clang issue, because both program are the same except STL. This is, possible, libc++ issue or, may be, this behaviour is implementation defined.

Comment: It was an attempt at answering your question, at least I almost never fstream's peek, seek, eof or flush.  So at least your code can be simplified, and then you can check if the problem still persists.

Comment: And I do not know why there is a difference, only that I would write your code like this : https://onlinegdb.com/pV0lWM2MF