# Reading & creating an object from txt file

Tags: c++

I have the fallowing function and i can't get it why it doesn't works. After saving the data is saved right but when reading it, it doesn't read the int parts.

```
void StudentRepository::loadStudents(){
    ifstream fl;
    fl.open("studs.txt");
    Student st("",0,0);
    string str,s;
    stringstream ss;
    int i;
    int loc;
    if(fl.is_open()){
        while(!(fl.eof())){
            getline(fl,str);
            loc = str.find(",");
            ss << str.substr(0,loc);
            s = ss.str();
            st.setName(s);
            str.erase(0,loc);
            loc = str.find(",");
            ss << str.substr(0,loc);
            ss >> i;
            st.setId(i);
            str.erase(0,loc);
            ss >> i;
            st.setGroup(i);
            students.push_back(st);

        }
    }
    else{
        cout<<"~~~ File couldn't be open! ~~~"<<endl;
    }
    fl.close();
}
```

eDIT:

```
class Student {
private:
    string name;
    int ID;
    int group;



public:
Student(string name, int id, int gr ):name(name),ID(id),group(gr){}

void setId(int value)       {group = value;}
void setGroup(int value)    {ID = value;}
void setName(string value)  {name = value;}
int getGroup()              const{return group;}
int getID()              const{return ID;}
    string getName()            const{return name;}

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Student& student)
    {
        out << student.name << " " << student.ID << " " << student.group <<endl;
        return out;
    }
};
```

file:(at print all int's are 0 as I initializate the object in the load function)

```
maier tsdar,2,0
staedfsgu aldasn,0,3
pdasdp aasdela,323,23
marsdaciu baleen,234,4534
madsd,234,2345
```

Comment: Can you please put the contents of the file you are trying to read here as well. As well as the definition of Student class.

Comment: don't use `eof()` like that, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6512278/4279

Answer (score 3):

When you are calling `s = ss.str();`, it does not consume the buffer, so the next time you try to extract an `int`, the extraction fails as the `ss` buffer still contains the initial string (and not just the string representation of the number that you appended at the end).  You could create a new stringstream object for the `int` extractions or consume all content before attempting to extract the `int`s

Comment: ...or empty the existing stringstream object with `ss.str("");`