# Why am I getting this error: expected ')' before '&' token?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I assume it has something to do with the #includes, but this is my first time trying to use them so I'm a little lost.  I just wondered if anyone could tell immediately if there was an obvious mistake.

```
 /** @file Translator.cpp */

#include <fstream>
#include "Translator.h"
#include <vector>

Translator(std::ifstream& fin)  //error appears on this line
{
    T1(fin);
    T1.createTable(fin);
    T2(fin);
    T2.createTable(fin));
    string temp;
    while(!fin.eof())
    {
    fin >> temp;
    message.push_back(temp);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Also you have an extra paren in `T2.createTable(fin));`

Comment: Also your loop should be `while (fin >> temp) message.push_back(temp);`, not `while (!fin.eof())`.

Comment: Thanks Seth.  Don't those two loops do the same thing?  What is the difference?

Comment: Nope, they're not equivalent. See this question/answer for the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14330789/726361

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is hard to answer this question exactly without seeing the header, but if this is a function, you need to add a return type of `void` to the definition of your function:

```
void Translator(std::ifstream& fin) {
    ...
}
```

If this is a constructor, you need to provide its qualified name:

```
Translator::Translator(std::ifstream& fin) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's supposed to be a parameterized constructor though.  I thought they didn't have a return type.

Comment: I guess the problem goes a lot deeper than I thought, because when I try Translator::Translator(..etc., I get 20 errors instead of just the one.

Comment: @ChrisHogan see my comments on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Without the declaration of `Translator` it's a bit hard to say, but if it's meant to be a constructor, then it should be `Translator::Translator(std::ifstream& fin)`. If it's meant to be a method, then it should have a return type specified, so something like `void Translator(std::ifstream& fin)`.