# when use fstream in cplusplus, what's wrong with this program

Tags: c++

The next program what's wrong? I prefer the file reach the end.

```
ifstream file("main.cpp", ios::binary | ios::ate);
if (file) {
    //fstream::pos_type size = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(100, fstream::cur);
    if (file.eof()) {
        cout << "eof is true\n";
    }
}
```

fstream reach the end of the file, but why not echo "eof is true".

Comment: Good question, yet another case showing that eof() doesn't do what almost every newbie thinks it should do.

Answer (score 7):

The eof bit is only set (and thus eof() only returns true) if an actual read operation fails due to hitting the end of the file. A seek operation (apparently) isn't enough.

Comment: but why next program is infinite loop?

ifstream file("main.cpp", ios::binary | ios::ate);

 if (file) {

  fstream::pos_type size = file.tellg();

  long len = 100;

  file.seekg(0, fstream::beg);


  while (!file.eof()) {

   fstream::pos_type rest_size = size - file.tellg();

   if (len > rest_size) len = rest_size;

   char* c = new char[len];

   file.read(c, len);

   delete []c;

   cout << rest_size << endl;

  }

 }

Comment: If you have a question with code, for heaven's sake post a new question. The code in this comment is completely unreadable. But I see a while(!file.eof()) in there, which is bad. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512173/ifstream-not-reading-eof-character

Comment: @minji_LT Because eof() is never true in your program. You have failures in your code but they are not end of file failures.