# ifstream eof function (C++)

Tags: c++, file, ifstream, eof

I have this code:

```
string a = "D:\\Users\\user-pc\\Desktop\\testing\\a.txt";

ifstream f;
    /*edit*/ string line;

    /*edit*/ getline(f, line);
f.open(a);
if ( f.eof() )
    cout << "ended";
else
    cout << "nope"
```

and the file 'a.txt' which has nothing in it.

the output is nope, alway nope. I don't get it.. Do I use it wrong?

EDIT: still .eof() not working

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ eof() problem - never returns true?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842030/c-eof-problem-never-returns-true)

Comment: `This function only reports the stream state as set by the most recent I/O operation, it does not examine the associated data source. ` In other words, you need to try to read first, then you can evaluate the state.

Comment: To elaborate the other comments: you would have to make an operation like `f.get()` and then check `f.eof()` - then it would be `true`. But then also, if file would not be empty, the first `char` would be thrown away. To do what you really intend, you could use `if ((f.rdbuf()->in_avail()) == 0)`. So you can really check how many chars are in the file without extracting them.

Comment: You need to open the file before using `getline` on the file.

Comment: A rule of thumb: Don't overwrite your post with the answer. It will confuse users who visit your question in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::basic_istream<...>::eof()` only returns true if a recent extraction set the appropriate bit in the stream state. When a file stream is constructed, its stream state is always that of `std::ios_base::goodbit`.

An alternative is to check if the next available character is the EOF character:

```
if (f.peek() == std::char_traits<char>::eof())
```

Comment: Your methood is working ! THANKS!

look at edit - still not good (the eof)

Comment: @user2410243 That's because you performed an extraction *before* you opened the file.

Comment: @user2410243 In other words, do `f.open(a);` before `getline(f, line);`.

Answer (score 1):

eofbit error state flag is only set once a read tries to read past the end of the file.